# How to use a 3x3 2D transformation in a vertex/fragment shader (Metal)

Tags: ios, shader, texture-mapping, metal

I have a supposedly simple task, but apparently I still don't understand how projections work in shaders. I need to do a 2D perspective transformation on a texture quad (2 triangles), but visually it doesn't look correct (e.g. trapezoid is slightly higher or more stretched than what it is in the CPU version).

I have this struct:

```
struct VertexInOut  
{  
  float4 position [[position]];  
  float3 warp0;  
  float3 warp1;  
  float3 warp2;  
  float3 warp3;  
};
```

And in the vertex shader I do something like (`texCoords` are pixel coords of the quad corners and homography is calculated in pixel coords):

```
v.warp0 = texCoords[vid] * homographies[0];
```

Then in the fragment shader like this:

```
return intensity.sample(s, inFrag.warp0.xy / inFrag.warp0.z);
```

The result is not what I expect. I spent hours on this, but I cannot figure it out. *venting*

**UPDATE:**

These are code and result for CPU (aka **expected result**):

```
// _image contains the original image
cv::Matx33d h(1.03140473, 0.0778113901, 0.000169219566,
              0.0342947133, 1.06025684, 0.000459250761,
              -0.0364957005, -38.3375587, 0.818259298);
cv::Mat dest(_image.size(), CV_8UC4);
// h is transposed because OpenCV is col major and using backwarping because it is what is used on the GPU, so better for comparison
cv::warpPerspective(_image, dest, h.t(), _image.size(), cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

[image: warped by cpu]

These are code and result for GPU (aka **wrong result**):

```
// constants passed in buffers, image size 320x240
const simd::float4 quadVertices[4] =
{
  { -1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
  { +1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
  { -1.0f,  +1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
  { +1.0f,  +1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
};

const simd::float3 textureCoords[4] =
{
  { 0,  IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1.0f },
  { IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1.0f },
  { 0, 0, 1.0f },
  { IMAGE_WIDTH, 0, 1.0f },
};

// vertex shader
vertex VertexInOut homographyVertex(uint vid [[ vertex_id ]],
                                    constant float4 *positions [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                    constant float3 *texCoords [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                    constant simd::float3x3 *homographies [[ buffer(2) ]])
{
  VertexInOut v;
  v.position = positions[vid];

  // example homography
  simd::float3x3 h = {
    {1.03140473, 0.0778113901, 0.000169219566},
    {0.0342947133, 1.06025684, 0.000459250761},
    {-0.0364957005, -38.3375587, 0.818259298}
  };

  v.warp = h * texCoords[vid];

  return v;
}

// fragment shader
fragment int4 homographyFragment(VertexInOut inFrag [[stage_in]],
                                 texture2d<uint, access::sample> intensity [[ texture(1) ]])
{
  constexpr sampler s(coord::pixel, filter::linear, address::clamp_to_zero);
  float4 targetIntensity = intensityRight.sample(s, inFrag.warp.xy / inFrag.warp.z);
  return targetIntensity;
}
```

[image]

Original image:

[image: original image]

**UPDATE 2:**

Contrary to the common belief that the perspective divide should be done in the fragment shader, I get a *much* more similar result if I divide in the vertex shader (and no distortion or seam between triangles), but why?

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

I get the same (wrong) result if:

- I move the perspective divide to the fragment shader
- I simply remove the divide from the code

Very strange, it looks like the divide is not happening.

Comment: Put up a project and I'll take a look at it. I can't give advice without at least a screenshot.

Comment: @Jessy I extracted the core part here, but if you need it I can create a full blown project. I have a custom client-server library to upload image XCTest results to my Mac, so it was much faster to extract this part of the code.

Comment: I fell asleep thinking on it, and woke up with the decision that I'd need to immerse myself in the project for it to be time-effective for me to solve it. If nobody else gets you an answer in a timeframe you're comfortable with, then yes, please find a way to upload the minimum of what we could work on, and I will make time to at least attempt to help.

Comment: Hey @Jessy, you can find an example app here: https://github.com/aledalgrande/warpExample When you run the app on an A7+ device you will be able to see the wrong warp in red. The right one is green and it is superimposed to the wrong one. There is some stretching due to the screen size, but as both are influenced by it, it makes no difference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just found out that the result of division was borked... if you try the app now you will see the image is yellow (all red pixels on top of green pixels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the solution was of course a very small detail: the **division** of `simd::float3` behaves absolutely nuts. In fact, if I do the perspective divide in the fragment shader like this:

```
float4 targetIntensity = intensityRight.sample(s, inFrag.warp.xy * (1.0 / inFrag.warp.z));
```

it works!

Which lead me to find out that multiplying by the pre-divided float is different than dividing by a float. The reason for this is still unknown to me, if anyone knows why we can unravel this mystery.

Comment: That's terrible! I have the same results that you describe, with your project. I changed the floats to halfs, but that didn't change the behavior.

Comment: I might open a radar, if nobody can figure out why this is happening.

Comment: The fact that both of us are surprised, and we both think it's wrong, means that it needs a radar filed, regardless of if the bug is with our own lack of knowledge. I've never seen anything like this with OpenGL/ES.